# Dishonored 2 pre-order didn't upgrade my copy of Dishonored 1

Tags: steam, dishonored, dishonored-2

I purchased Dishonored 1 through Steam when it came out.

I pre-ordered Dishonored 2 recently through Steam, and it warned me that I wouldn't get a second copy of the first game with my purchase. However, I see now that it gives you the Definitive Edition of the first game with your pre-order of the second game.

I never bought any of the DLC for the first game, so why did it not upgrade my game and give me the DLC?

Comment: Did you check to see if maybe you had another version of the game in your library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like a bug.  You should contact Steam support, there is nothing we can do for you here.

Comment: Okay, so it now shows the DLC in my library. When I checked last time, it didn't show up. Guess it took a while for it to process or something. My bad.

Comment: Glad to know that I was wrong then, enjoy your DLC for that.

Answer (score 1):

You kind of answered your own question. When you bought Dishonored 2 you said it gave you a message about not receiving a second copy of Dishonored 1. When you take part in offers such as this if you own any form of the original copy you will not receive the second GOTY copy of it. Bethesda isn't lying since you do already own the game, so they are not giving you a second copy. It's kind of scummy I know but I don't think there is much you can do about it besides just buying the DLC separately.

Comment: I disagree. It is lying because I do not own "Dishonored: The Definitive Edition". And they failed to give it to me. Yes, I agreed that I was okay with it when I bought the second game, but it is still lying. I realize that there is nothing I can do, other than refund the game. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Like I said it is kind of a scummy practice but that's just the way it is. Their reasoning is that the DLC is a separate part of the package since when you purchase the definitive edition it still shows up as Dishonored, not Dishonored Definitive Edtion. The DLC is separate add ons to it. But like I said, I don't agree with that practice but the devs have final say in the matter.

Comment: I didn't realize that when you get the Definitive Edition, it still shows up as regular Dishonored. Not that that makes a difference, but it makes it easier for them to be scummy about it. Thanks for your replies. I'm gonna delete my question, as it wasn't really a real question to begin with

Comment: No need to delete the question, just mark it as answered. It is a helpful source if other people want to ask about it.

Comment: -1 that message is meant to mean you won't receive a tradable copy of the game to give to a friend, not that the copy in your library won't be upgraded.  It should be upgraded, this sounds like a Steam bug.